# Execute function c# from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want execute function c# like `Convert.ToInt32([data]);` `DateTime.ParseExact("[data]", "dd MMM yyyy", provider` from string. Before execute, I replace the data before

Example:

```
string aa = "Convert.ToInt32([data]);"
aa = aa.Replace("[data]", "1");
//var bb = result execute from aa
```

How to exexute like this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

Comment: There is [a lot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=C%23+execute+string+as+code&oq=C%23+execute+string+as+code&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0j69i60j0l2.3744j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) written about this topic already. What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: Possibile duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments

Comment: Take a look into this related topic : https://stackoverflow.com/a/540089/5916272

Comment: Thank all. I will try to understand. I'm still confused.. iI think not `int bb` but `var bb`. Bcuse not always int for result..

Comment: @Stfvns -- Using my answer is a generic. So if you were expecting a string result, for example, you'd just change it to: `string bb = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(aa);`.

Comment: @Icemanind for exacly I will don't know the variable result because i will many result like `int, date, decimal`. Because I will do looping from table.. before this question, I have another question before `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893131/how-to-insert-model-from-mapping-table`. Anybody can help me?

Comment: @Stfvns - `var` does not mean the type will change dynamically. The type is still determined by the compiler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

Comment: But I can't know the variable result. Could you take a look my another question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893131/how-to-insert-model-from-mapping-table` please @BrootsWaymb

Comment: Will it always be this kind of conversion / string-parsing function you want to execute? Or will it be any arbitrary c# code?

Comment: Check out (possible duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file
The CSharpCodeProvider class looks like promising.

Comment: I still can't implement all the answer all :(

Comment: @Stfvns `var` is evaluated at compile-time, not dynamically at run-time. However, you may be able to use `dynamic` instead.

Comment: Agreed, using dynamic could be a way forward

Answer (score 4):

[Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) is the easiest way to do this:

```
int bb = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(aa);
```

Answer (score -6):

Seems like the example ins't too clear. I think you could use String Interpolation to accomplish what you are looking for.

Like:
$"Coin flip: {(rand.NextDouble() < 0.5 ? "heads" : "tails")}"

Here is the reference to MSDN documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation

Comment: This isn't related to string interpolation whatsoever. I don't see how this would solve OP's problem.